# Angularjs send empty JSON to server (ONLY in IE 9 and greater)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, internet-explorer

I have a little issue with my angularjs script.
I'm trying to post data to server (PHP script which saves values to database).
It works correctly in Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and each other but totally not in IE. I tried IE9, 10 and also 11 (all without add-ons)and still can't figure it out.
In IE my angularjs posts only empty JSON (something like {}).

Here's my angularjs POST script.

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {

            // Posting data to php file
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'ajax/newInvoice.php',
                data    : $scope.invoice, //forms user object
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                 
            })
                .success(function(data) {
                    getInvoices();
                    $scope.invoice = {items: [{qty: 1,description: '',cost: 0,taxPerc: 21}],odberatel: '',konecny_prijemce: '',datum_objednavky: new Date(),datum_vystaveni: new Date(),datum_splatnosti: new Date(),datum_zdanitelneho_plneni: new Date(),zpusob_uhrady: 'Platba kartou',dodaci_metoda: 'Osobní odběr'};           
                });
        };
```

And here's PHP.

```
<?php

require_once '../includes/db.php'; // The mysql database connection script

$created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"));

$query = "SELECT id FROM ang_faktury ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$last_invoice_id = intval($row["id"]);
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$idString = str_pad(($last_invoice_id + 1), 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);//id faktury ang_faktury[id], ang_faktury_polozky[id_faktury]
$faCislo = 'OB/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$idString; //cislo faktury ang_faktury[cislo_faktury]

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$dzp = $_POST['datum_zdanitelneho_plneni'];
$datum_zdanitelneho_plneni = substr($dzp, 0, 10);   
$dzpForm = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($datum_zdanitelneho_plneni));

$do = $_POST['datum_objednavky'];
$datum_objednavky = substr($do, 0, 10); 
$doForm = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($datum_objednavky));

$dv = $_POST['datum_vystaveni'];
$datum_vystaveni = substr($dv, 0, 10);  
$dvForm = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($datum_vystaveni));

$ds = $_POST['datum_splatnosti'];
$datum_splatnosti = substr($ds, 0, 10);
$dsForm = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($datum_splatnosti));

foreach($_POST['items'] as $item){      
    $sumPriceTotal += $item['priceTotal'];
    $query2="insert into ang_faktury_polozky (id_faktury,name,cena,ks,dph_proc,dph,total) values('$idString','$item[description]','$item[mjPrice]','$item[qty]','$item[taxPerc]','$item[taxSum]','$item[priceTotal]')";
    $mysqli->query($query2);
}

$spt = "{$sumPriceTotal}";
$cbd = (($spt*100)/121);
$dph = $spt - $cbd;

$query3="insert into ang_faktury (id,created_at,cislo_faktury,datum_zdanitelneho_plneni,odberatel,konecny_prijemce,zpusob_uhrady,dodaci_metoda,cislo_objednavky,datum_objednavky,datum_vystaveni,datum_splatnosti,cena_bez_dph,dph,celkem_k_uhrade) values('$idString','$created','$faCislo','$dzpForm','$_POST[odberatel]','$_POST[konecny_prijemce]','$_POST[zpusob_uhrady]','$_POST[dodaci_metoda]','$faCislo','$doForm','$dvForm','$dsForm','$cbd','$dph','$spt')";
$mysqli->query($query3);

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Could you try a "normal" angular post? `$http.post('ajax/newInvoice.php', $scope.invoice, config).then(console.log);` Also note that it's considered better to move ajax calls/etc out of controllers and into services. It shouldn't affect if it works or not though, just improving code structure/separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your data before sending `console.log(data)`,
and check your data after receiving `print_r($_POST)` (in myFile.php)

Comment: Thank you all,
I checked my code again and found that I was calling some odd function which reloads whole page but before than data were sent to server :o)

Answer (score 0):

from console (newInvoice.php):

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [description] => MIKI_01
                    [cost] => 10
                    [taxPerc] => 21
                    [priceTotal] => 10.00
                    [taxSum] => 1.74
                    [mjPrice] => 8.26
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [description] => MIKI_02
                    [cost] => 20
                    [taxPerc] => 21
                    [priceTotal] => 20.00
                    [taxSum] => 3.47
                    [mjPrice] => 16.53
                )

        )

    [odberatel] => MIKI
    [konecny_prijemce] => 
    [datum_objednavky] => 2016-01-16T13:39:32.554Z
    [datum_vystaveni] => 2016-01-16T13:39:32.554Z
    [datum_splatnosti] => 2016-01-16T13:39:32.554Z
    [datum_zdanitelneho_plneni] => 2016-01-16T13:39:32.554Z
    [zpusob_uhrady] => Platba kartou
    [dodaci_metoda] => Osobní odběr
)
```

Console (app.js)

```
Object {items: Array[2], odberatel: "MIKI", konecny_prijemce: "", datum_objednavky: Sat Jan 16 2016 14:45:18 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time), datum_vystaveni: Sat Jan 16 2016 14:45:18 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)…}
datum_objednavky: Sat Jan 16 2016 14:45:18 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
datum_splatnosti: Sat Jan 16 2016 14:45:18 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
datum_vystaveni: Sat Jan 16 2016 14:45:18 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
datum_zdanitelneho_plneni: Sat Jan 16 2016 14:45:18 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
dodaci_metoda: "Osobní odběr"
items: Array[2]
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:4"
cost: 10
description: "MIKI_01"
mjPrice: "8.26"
priceTotal: "10.00"
qty: 1
taxPerc: 21
taxSum: "1.74"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
$$hashKey: "object:69"
cost: 20
description: "MIKI_02"
mjPrice: "16.53"
priceTotal: "20.00"
qty: 1
taxPerc: 21
taxSum: "3.47"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
konecny_prijemce: ""
odberatel: "MIKI"
zpusob_uhrady: "Platba kartou"
__proto__: Object
```